# What type of battery is used for the Canon EF Adapter XL for Canon XL-2 and XL-1 DV Camcorders

Tags: canon

Please provide full battery specifications if you can for the Canon EF Adapter XL for Canon XL-2 and XL-1 DV Camcorders to mount EOS Photo Lenses BH #CAEFAXL1 • MFR #3162A002

Comment: What does the manual say? Shouldn't be too hard to find an online version...

Comment: I couldn't find any battery related info on line for this.

Answer (score 3):

The second link when I Google "Canon EF Adapter XL manual" brings up [this](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Canon-Ef-Adapter-Xl-2805894.html) (the first one was in Japanese, which I don't read), which, on page 12, under "Replacing the lithium battery", mentions that the battery is a "2CR5". Googling "2CR5 battery" comes up with many links for where you can get them - Walgreens, Grainger, Amazon, Best Buy, ....... Most of them also give details - like it's a 6V rechargeable lithium battery.

Comment: Ok.... care to explain the down-vote? OP apparently did no original research, and the answer points out that 30 seconds of research could completely answer the question....